# How to pass async method delegate in async method call?

Tags: asynchronous, delegates

I have two async methods:

```
 private async Task<string> Method_1_Async(string parameter)
        { return await LongRunningFunction_1();} 
 private async Task<string> Method_2_Async(string parameter)
        { return await LongRunningFunction_2();}
```

I need to call them in a third async method passing the method name as a parameter. Something like this:

```
public  async Task<string> Method_3_Async(DelegateMethodClass methodName, string parameter)
        { return await methodName(parameter);}
```

How should `DelegateMethodClass` be declared? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions are the same as any other function when it comes to their method signature--the return type specified in your code as well as the types and ordering of the parameters for the basis for either a custom delegate type like...

```
private delegate Task<string> MyAsyncFunction(string parameter)
```

Or using one of the general-purpose generic delegate types like `Func<string, Task<string>>`.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
public async Task<string> Method_3_Async(Func<string, Task<string>> methodName, string parameter)
{
    return await methodName(parameter);
}
```

This specific case could be simplified not to use `async` and `await` since you aren't actually doing anything with the returned value or awaiting anything prior to that task, but I assume that your actual implementation is more complex.